# What are browsers or web servers doing "behind the scenes" regarding URL UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: http, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Consider these two URLs:

- http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=Welcome%20home%2C%20Linn%C3%A9a
- http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?&tl=en&q=Welcome%20home%2C%20Linn%C3%A9a

One includes an explicit parameter to tell google translate text-to-speech that the encoding is UTF-8.

On Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.107), Safari (Version 7.0.1 (9537.73.11)), these URLs yield identical spoken output.

However, on Mobile Safari, URL loading through e.g., VLC, or through a command-line argument to e.g., mpg321, translate.google.com considers the URL to be encoded differnetly, and reads of "©" (copyright) rather than an "é."

Digging into the Chrome headers that are sent as part of the request, I can't find any reference to encoding.

- Is this happening silently in the browser? Is it happening visibly
  and I am missing it?
- Or is it something that happens on the server-side implicitly
  depending on what browser is sending a request?

N.B. that I am not asking about the browsers "pretty-printing" the URL text. Inspection confirms that the encoding is getting sent as the %-escaped string behind the scenes, just as it is

Comment: It'll be Google's servers guessing an arbitrary default encoding to use to interpret the input, but I personally can't reproduce the guess of ISO-8859-1 for this text (which results in %A9 being a copyright), neither by spoofing my User-Agent to pretend to be Mobile Safari, nor by using VLC or mpg123.

Comment: Huh, that's pretty interesting.

Do you think "Server" here means server, or scripting layer, or is that immaterial?

Comment: It would have to be in the application layer somewhere (part of app or framework) as web servers don't themselves take part in the URL-decoding of query string components.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Submit as an answer and I will mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

URLs do not support non-ASCII Unicode characters, so they must be charset-encoded and url-encoded (IRIs, on the other hand, support unencoded Unicode characters). The charset used for the encoding of Unicode characters is at the discretion of websites, not web browsers. There is no way for a URL or an HTTP header to specify which charset is being using in the URL (the `ie=UTF-8` portion is arbitrary input data for the `translate_tts` script, not a controlling factor of the URL itself).  MOST websites nowadays use UTF-8, but not all do (many foreign sites, like Russian sites, assume local encoding), so web browsers tend to default to UTF-8 unless configured otherwise.  Which will obviously not work on websites that are not expecting UTF-8.  Typically it is a website that is creating the URLs that web browsers then use, so the websites decide how they want their own URLs formatted.

Comment: There's a lot in here -- I understand that the ie=UTF-8 is just a parameter of the script, and that URLs need to be encoded into a charset.

What surprises me is that the site (and are we talking about the server layer or the web-backends that are implemented on top of that?) would make different encoding choices for different agents visiting the site. 

(Edited for premature submission)